# ODBC Source Error Open Database Connectivity error occured

Tags: mysql, ssis, odbc, etl

Getting an error from a MYSQL Source checked to see that the table actually match and they do. I have recreated the odbc source and checked the connection string but still giving the error.

> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The
> PrimeOutput method on ODBC Source MySource returned error code
> 0x80004005.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline
> engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is
> defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline
> stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this
> with more information about the failure.
>
> [ODBC Source MySource [40]] Error: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC)
> error occurred. state: '01004'. Native Error Code: 0. [MySQL][ODBC
> 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.47-log]

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};server=0.0.0.0;uid=MyUser;database=NYDatabase;port=0000
```

any suggestions to fix the problem ?

checked to see that the table actually match and they do. I have recreated the odbc source and checked the connection string but still giving the error.

[image: Rough Picture of the running system]

Comment: port is usually 3306 not 0000

Comment: my port is 3306 i just changed all the info on the connection string as to not violate any safety protocols

Comment: as izt tries to make a named pipe so you have a mysql in localhost. If not you will have a problem which Servers on other maschines, as long as it is in the LAN you ca gie the port free i the forewall, but if you try to access one server in the internet it will block the connection, becuase it is very unsafe to have an oen mysql server in the internet. as you see you have not enough information even to make a educated guess

Comment: the source (MYSQL DB) is in Azure and the destination (SQL) db is on the local machine running the SSIS package.  From other connection errors everyone points toward the ODBC driver being the problem but i have not seen any solution towards that problem. I am running the 32 bit ODB driver .  What other type of information should i list ?

Comment: Also the error only appears on some of the tables the other tables load fine

Comment: the word azure isn't mentioned in your question, also where is the ssis running local or o azure? like i said ssis tries to open a named piped which isn't present, so your connection strin g isn't  using tcpip, instead it tries to find a named pipe on the computer that has ssis running, so describe inyour question very detailed the hole system maybe make an image, you have to remeber that we don't know nothing about your setup

Comment: Source (MYSQL Azure DB)  destination is a onprem server which is also running the SSIS package

Comment: this are the connection string for odbc https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/mysql/single-server/how-to-connection-string  see if you have the same